# Receiving SAML Logout response at /Saml2/Acs point

Tags: saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2, single-logout

In my application single logout works fine but after logout request processed on Idp i am getting response at /Saml2/Acs point. I am not sure where does this URL come from,so is there any particular way to configure this end point at SP side because i don't have control over Idp.

To provide additional details following are Login/Logout request responses

```html
<!-- Loging Request -->
<saml2p:AuthnRequest
    AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://service.provider.com/server/Saml2/Acs"
    Destination="https://identity.provider.com/nidp/saml2/sso" ID="id969024c5919e47148622d87bd40724ad"
    IssueInstant="2019-04-08T10:51:03Z" Version="2.0"
    xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
    xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml2:Issuer>https://service.provider.com</saml2:Issuer>
    <saml2p:NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified"/>
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>
<!-- Loging Request -->
<!-- ##### -->
<!-- Login Response -->
<samlp:Response Destination="https://service.provider.com/server/Saml2/Acs"
    ID="idNammIIHbKBac2pGfdbHqHFTwy9w" InResponseTo="id969024c5919e47148622d87bd40724ad"
    IssueInstant="2019-04-08T10:51:49Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml:Issuer>https://identity.provider.com/nidp/saml2/metadata</saml:Issuer>
    <samlp:Status><samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/></samlp:Status>
    <saml:Assertion ID="idqn4Szd8L-wAJQojG9-4j-JAaXzo" IssueInstant="2019-04-08T10:51:49Z" Version="2.0">
        <saml:Issuer>https://identity.provider.com/nidp/saml2/metadata</saml:Issuer>
        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                <ds:Reference URI="#idqn4Szd8L-wAJQojG9-4j-JAaXzo">
                    <ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                    <DigestValue xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">/KjwtCOlMQllJ8/rw22iowBNeEM=</DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                SIGNARTURE-REMOVED
            </SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo>
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>
                        CERTIFICATE-REMOVED
                    </ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </ds:Signature>
        <saml:Subject>
            <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified"
                NameQualifier="https://identity.provider.com/nidp/saml2/metadata"
                SPNameQualifier="https://service.provider.com">00001234</saml:NameID>
            <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"><saml:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="id969024c5919e47148622d87bd40724ad"
                NotOnOrAfter="2019-04-08T10:56:49Z"
                Recipient="https://service.provider.com/server/Saml2/Acs"/></saml:SubjectConfirmation>
        </saml:Subject>
        <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2019-04-08T10:46:49Z" NotOnOrAfter="2019-04-08T10:56:49Z">
            <saml:AudienceRestriction>
                <saml:Audience>https://service.provider.com</saml:Audience>
            </saml:AudienceRestriction>
        </saml:Conditions>
        <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2019-04-08T10:45:27Z"
            SessionIndex="idqn4Szd8L-wAJQojG9-4j-JAaXzo">
            <saml:AuthnContext>
                <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
            </saml:AuthnContext>
        </saml:AuthnStatement>
        <saml:AttributeStatement>
            <saml:Attribute Name="achternaam"
                NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">LastName</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="rollen" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">role</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="mail" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">f.lastname@company.come</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="tussenvoegsel"
                NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">middle</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="voornaam" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">FirstName</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="uniqueid" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">00001234</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
        </saml:AttributeStatement>
    </saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
<!-- Login Response -->
<!-- ##### -->
<!-- Logout Request -->
<saml2p:LogoutRequest Destination="https://identity.provider.com/nidp/saml2/slo"
    ID="idd2e66a13b3ed43b29a9fd06724723ea2" IssueInstant="2019-04-08T10:52:54Z" Version="2.0"
    xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
    xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml2:Issuer>https://service.provider.com</saml2:Issuer>
    <saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified"
        NameQualifier="https://identity.provider.com/nidp/saml2/metadata"
        SPNameQualifier="https://service.provider.com">00001234</saml2:NameID>
    <saml2p:SessionIndex>idqn4Szd8L-wAJQojG9-4j-JAaXzo</saml2p:SessionIndex>
</saml2p:LogoutRequest>
<!-- Logout Request -->
<!-- ##### -->
<!-- Logout Response -->
<samlp:LogoutResponse Destination="https://service.provider.com/server/Saml2/Acs"
    ID="idIANzyBI5tg2fB2dWOxcSrDA4bko" InResponseTo="idd2e66a13b3ed43b29a9fd06724723ea2"
    IssueInstant="2019-04-08T10:52:55Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml:Issuer>https://identity.provider.com/nidp/saml2/metadata</saml:Issuer>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
            <ds:Reference URI="#idIANzyBI5tg2fB2dWOxcSrDA4bko">
                <ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                <DigestValue xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">dcdadDJVjgx1hzfs/OK0eBHVbEc=</DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            SIGNARTURE-REMOVED
        </SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo>
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>
                    CERTIFICATE-REMOVED
                </ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
    <samlp:Status><samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/></samlp:Status>
</samlp:LogoutResponse>
<!-- Logout Response -->
```

Answer (score 1):

A 'single logout service' should be configured on the service provider with the location set to where you would like the SP to re-direct the user after logging out from the Identity Provider.

To check to see if this is configured properly, you could print out the metadata for your SP.  As you can see in the metadata below, my SP has been configured with a SingleLogoutService (this is where the logout requests and responses are sent from the IdP).

```
<SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://localhost:3000/auth/saml-logout-callback"/>
```

The SingleLogoutService has a location of "http://localhost:3000/auth/saml-logout-callback" meaning that the SP will send the user to /auth/saml-logout-callback on receiving a Logout Response.  Of course, your SP should be configured to send the user to a different endpoint in dev than in production.

Setting up this this was pretty straight forward for me because I am using the Passport SAML library to configure the SP options.  So, if you are using a library to communicate with SAML, there might be some good options to configure the SP single logout location.  In passport, you specify the logout url as a parameter when declaring the SAML strategy.

I've written some more about the general workflow for signing out here:  https://spin.atomicobject.com/2019/04/06/saml-2-0-flow/